# ReactJS removing item from array removes all other elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Following my app.js

```
import Form from "./Containers/Form";
import { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import List from "./Containers/List";

function App() {
let [items,setItems] = useState([]);
const handleAdd = useCallback((item)=>{
    let newItems=[...items,item];
        setItems(newItems)
},[items])
const onEdit=useCallback((odlv,newv)=>{
        let newItems=items.map((item)=>{
            if(item===odlv){
                return newv;
            }
            return item
        });
        setItems(newItems)

},[items]);

const onDelete=(odlv)=>{
    console.log("old",odlv)
    let newItems=items.filter((item)=>{
        return (item!==odlv)
    });
    setItems(newItems)
}
return ( <div className = "container" >
                <Form onAdd={handleAdd}/>
                <List items={[...items]} onEdit={onEdit} onDelete={onDelete} />
        </div >
);
}

  export default App;
```

And my list item.js

```
import InputBox from "./InputBox"

import { useMemo, useState, useCallback } from "react"

export default function Item(props){
        let [edit,setEdit]=useState(false)
        let [taskDetail,setTaskDetail]=useState(props.item)
        let [error,setError]=useState('')
        let handleSave=useCallback(()=>{
            if(taskDetail==''){
                setError('Please Enter Task Details')
            }else{
                if(taskDetail!==props.item)
                {
                    setError('')
                    props.onEdit(props.item,taskDetail)
                    setEdit(false)
                }
            }

        },[edit,taskDetail,error])


        const handleTaskUpdate=useCallback((e)=>{
            setTaskDetail(e.target.value)
        },[])

        let [titleDisplay,editButton,deleteButton]=useMemo(()=>{
            if(edit){
                return [<InputBox value={taskDetail} error={error} onChange={handleTaskUpdate}
                />,<button onClick={handleSave} className='btn btn-success '>Save</button>,<button onClick={()=>{setEdit(false)}} className='ms-1 btn btn-danger'>Cancel</button>]
            }
            return [<h5>{props.item}</h5>,<button onClick={()=>setEdit(true)} className='btn btn-secondary '>Edit</button>,<button className='ms-1 btn btn-danger' onClick={()=>{props.onDelete(taskDetail)}}>Delete</button>];
        },[edit,taskDetail,error])

        return<li className='list-group-item'>
                <div className='row'>
                        <div className='col-md-6'>{titleDisplay}</div>
                        <div className='col-md-6'>
                            {editButton}{deleteButton}
                        </div>
            </div>
            
        </li>
  }
```

When I click on delete, it works fine for last node deletion but when middle node is deleted it removed all other node expect the first one
like try adding
A, B, C, D
remove D will work fine
but remove B will remove C and D

What's going wrong?

Comment: inside `useMemo` you are using `props.item`, `props.onDelete`, `setEdit` but they are not declared as dependencies of the hook. Try adding them and see if it works.

Comment: it will be greate if you can give detailed answer pointing to the rule to use memo in such a case

Comment: You mean how `useMemo` works ?

Comment: yes,so this may be useful to other for same issue,what i did wrong and what is the correct way to do the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem occurs because `useMemo` is missing dependencies. In this case `props.item`, `props.onDelete`, `setEdit`
If you don't pass these required arguments as dependencies useMemo will no recalculate what is inside the callback and will continue using the old `momoized` values, thus props.items was the same variable containing the same values even if you removed some of them.
When you delete one item and this variable is part of the dependencies, react knows that it's changed and `useMemo` is recalculated.